# What are the possible numpy value format strings?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, format

In numpy, many functions have a string which can be passed as an additional argrument to format numpy array values.

In  `numpy.loadtxt` for example, http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

The following can be chosen

```
"%10.5f"
"%.4e %+.4j"
```

And it mentions in the documentation:

"Further explanation of the fmt parameter (`%[flag]width[.precision]specifier`):"

Exactly what are the possible formats?

What are possible values for `flag`, `width`, `precision`, and `specifier` ?

Bonus points for someone who explains when they can be mixed and matched... `'Iteration %d – %10.5f’` is mentioned in the documentation...

Comment: I'd say the documentation you've linked to covers this pretty well; the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) they've linked to covers this in even more detail. I'm not sure what else you're asking for here...

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the additional reference! After trying a few which work on sprintf it would appear that a few don't seem to work on numpy arrays the same way. "%s" seems to fail for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`np.savetxt` is using the old-fashioned (Py2) `%` style formatting.  The key line is:

```
for row in X:
    fh.write(asbytes(format % tuple(row) + newline))
```

where `format` is your `fmt` parameter, or constructed from it:

```
# `fmt` can be a string with multiple insertion points or a
# list of formats.  E.g. '%10.5f\t%10d' or ('%10.5f', '$10d')
```

(I'm puzzled about that '$10d' string.  Is that a typo?

In essence if there are enough `%` in a string `fmt`, it is used as is.  If it's a list it joins them with the delimited.  If a single format, it replicates it and joins.

The row the array is turned into a `tuple`, which is normal input to `%` formatting.

So `savetxt` is straight forward Python number formatting.

I think it's the only `numpy` function that operates this way.  There's a separate formatter than handles the `print` display of arrays.

========================

example:

Fully specified `fmt` string:

```
In [22]: np.savetxt('text.txt',np.ones((2,4)),fmt='%s: %10d, %10.5fl %.4e')

In [23]: cat text.txt
1.0:          1,    1.00000l 1.0000e+00
1.0:          1,    1.00000l 1.0000e+00
```

Use of that `fmt` directly with a tuple of integers:

```
In [24]: '%s: %10d, %10.5fl %.4e'%(1,1,1,1)
Out[24]: '1:          1,    1.00000l 1.0000e+00'
```

and with a tuple of floats (note change the 1st %s format)

```
In [25]: '%s: %10d, %10.5fl %.4e'%(1.,1.,1.,1.)

Out[25]: '1.0:          1,    1.00000l 1.0000e+00'
```

Answer (score 2):

The possible formats are listed at [format specification mini-language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) in the Python Standard Library documentation.

Width and precision are decimal integers. Unless a minimum field width is defined, the field width will always be the same size as the data to fill it.

Presentation types include:
"b" | "c" | "d" | "e" | "E" | "f" | "F" | "g" | "G" | "n" | "o" | "s" | "x" | "X" | "%"